# Why was Colossal marketed the way it was?

Tags: marketing, trailers, colossal

SPOILERS BELOW!

The 2017 movie Colossal was marketed to be a fun film with monsters and supernatural powers. Right from the music to the dialogues picked in the trailer read "funny monster movie".

Here's the trailer - [Colossal Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqcZtz8VXXE)

However the film was far from being a "funny monster movie". It had some deep themes like alcoholism and bad influences/relationships. Everyone who went thinking it was a monster movie had to reconfigure their expectations as they sat and watched the film. Only a few succeeded doing that.. everyone else came out saying it was an odd monster movie where nothing was clear.

**Any idea why this misdirection?** Had the trailer mimicked the core themes of the movie (eg: Enemy or any Lynch film) the film could have done far better? It was an amazing movie i thought?

Comment: I saw it for the director and this director doesn't do that. I believe you know about Time Crimes. I'm asking this - had the film been marketed for what it actually was, it would have got more viewership and satisfied customers too.

Answer (score 5):

According to multiple sources, from interviews to film reviews, it appears that there was a blip on the radar from the beginning which revolved around Toho (the owners of the Godzilla franchise) suing them for using a Godzilla look-alike in emails when they were looking for financing.  Since that was the "big news" on the film, and that story was easier to sell in 30-second spots, that was the story they pushed forward.

I saw him comment on one site (which I can't remember) that it's less a satire on Kaiju and is more a satire on RomComs and their predictability.

[This review](http://www.filmjournal.com/features/colossal-surprise-nacho-vigalondos-latest-betrays-expectations-monster-sized-way) specifically mentions in its first paragraph how defying expectations isn't a bad thing.

> In this age of beefed-up movie marketing, it’s rare to find a movie
>   willing to actively surprise its audience. Between trailers, teasers,
>   teasers for trailers and Instagram videos for teasers for trailers, by
>   the time your 21st moviegoer steps into a theatre, they generally know
>   what to expect, in broad strokes if not in the specifics. [clip] That
>   doesn’t mean the movies themselves are bad. But order variations on
>   the same meal at the same restaurant for long enough, and eventually
>   you’re going to want something different.

I'd suggest checking out a few of the results from this Google search: [Colossal movie marketing](https://www.google.com/search?q=nacho+vigalondo+colossal&oq=Nacho+Vigalondo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3256j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=colossal+movie+marketing)